# changing navigation in magento dynamically

Tags: magento

I want to know that can i change the navigation menu dynamically,i am having two tabs on the basis of which i want to render the navigation menu.How can it be done

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For usability reasons, the global navigation generally shouldn't change. Users will expect to see the same options available to them and will get confused (and leave) if they aren't.

Could you explain the requirement more?

---

EDIT:

Usability issues aside, try adding all necessary items to the top nav, then use Javascript to toggle between tabs. If you don't want to change the navigation PHTML files to add IDs to them, you can use the existing classes to target which nav items to show and which to hide.

Since Magento stores cannot function without JS anyway, you should be pretty safe with that solution. Preferably, you can change the top nav's template (I believe `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml` in 1.4) to use IDs for those LIs as well, in which case you can target those instead.

Thanks,
Joe